# Sprites in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprite

Is there a way to make and use sprites with Rails 3.1 (without external gem) ? I saw methods like sprite_tag or sprite_css but I am not able to use them!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sprites and Ruby on Rails are unrelated. You can use a online sprite generator such as this: http://css-sprit.es/

Comment: @Swanand: Sprites can be made (much) easier with Scss, now used by default in Rails 3.1, see for example my answer, so they can most definitely be related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 3.1 does not have a spriting solution out of the box even though it had been pre-announced it would (see slide 10 of [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/hagenburger/3-waystocreatespritesinrails)).

Until it does, one (external gem) solution you can use is [compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/).